# IMO shortlist problem-need hints to carry on with this solution.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

There are $n$ lamps $L_1,....,L_n$ in a row, each on or off. After each second, we simultaneously modify the state of each lamp as follows:

1.) If $L_i$ is in the same state as each of its neighbours, it is switched off(remains off if it was already off)

2.) If $L_i$ is in a different state to atleast one of its neighbours, it is switched on(remains on if it was already on)

Prove that there are infinite values of $n$ for which all lamps eventually turn off, as well as infinite values of $n$ for which all lamps never turn off, if initially all lamps except the leftmost $L_1$ are off.

Solution:

we define $f(n,k)$ as the number of lamps that are off after $k$ seconds.
As we actually carry out the algorithm, we note:

$f(n,0)$ $=$ $n - 1$

$f(n,1)$ $=$ $n - 2$

$f(n,2)$ $=$ $n - 2$

$f(n,3)$ $=$ $n - 4$

$f(n,4)$ $=$ $n - 2$

$f(n,5)$ $=$ $n - 4$

$f(n,6)$ $=$ $n - 4$

$f(n,7)$ $=$ $n - 8$

$f(n,8)$ $=$ $n - 2$

As such, we guess $f(n,k)$ is of the form $n - 2^m$, where $2^m$ is some power of $2$ if k isn't a power of $2$, and $n - 2$ if $k$ is a power of $2$. Note, if this claim is true, it simultaneously proves both parts, since we get that all $n$ that are not powers of $2$ will never have $f(n,k)$ reach $0$(the number of bulbs that are off can't be negative) and, all $n$ that are powers of $2$ can reach zero. Now, we also consider the lamps as sequences of letters $O$ and $F$ and note that any transition from $F$ to $O$ or $O$ to $F$ turns into two $O's$. This would seem to imply that there is always an even number of bulbs that are on, but there can also transitions of the form $OFO$ which turn into $OOO$. It is true then that the number of bulbs that are on could be expressed in the form $2q + 3p$, but that's not good enough, since every integer except $1$ can be expressed in that form. I need hints on how to prove that claim.

Comment: Your claim is most probably not true, or at least you're implicitly assuming $ k < n$ (and hence gives us no information about the infinite seconds). E.g. for $n = 3, f(3,3) = -1$ doesn't make sense. There might be difficulty with dealing with the tail end, since the state changes there impact the infinite case, so this approach will not prove that "lamps will never be all off"

Comment: The claim is that, basically the number of bulbs that are on is always a power of 2. I added that list because that list hints towards it. For 3,3, there are 2 bulbs that are on, which is a power of 2

Comment: My point is that (I suspect) you've only been looking at $k<<n$, and ignoring tail end effects.  Because powers of 2 seem to behave nicely, you need to look at "much higher than powers of 2" to potentially find a counter example. For example, with 7 lamps, after the 7th second, all 7 lamps are on. In particular, the 6th second is where I think your idealized interpretation of the setup fails to work.

Comment: OFFFFFF ==> OOFFFFF ==> FOOFFFF ==> OOOOFFF ==> FFFOOFF ==> FFOOOOF ==> FOOFFOO ==> OOOOOOF => FFFFFOO. So not all on, but in the second last step 6 are on, which isn't a power of 2, so I suppose the claim is wrong. What do you suggest would work instead?

Comment: (Ah, I got the 7th bulb in the 7th second wrong.)  You're on a good path, I suggest 1) playing with larger values of $n,k$ to get a sense of what could work - IE If you haven't calculated (7,7), then there is a lot further for you to tabulate first. 2) you don't have to investigate all $n$, just infinitely many $n$. 3) When things are even / powers of 2, there seems to be some kind of a pattern. 4) When things are much larger than a power of 2, the patterns break down. This suggests that we should be looking at numbers of the form $ 2^k, 2^k + 1, 2^k + 2 , \ldots, 2^k + k, 2^k + 2k, \ldots $.

Comment: 5) Think about what techniques could be used. IE That the sequence will be eventually periodic tells us that the "never all off" scenario likely involves characterizing this loop for some $n$.  While invariance comes to mind, it is hard for me to see what the invariance is. Greedy algorithm is clearly not relevant. 6) Based on these, you should have enough to proceed. If not, tabulate results up till $n = 20$.

Comment: Your third and 4th hints were really helpful. I tabulated more. It seemed that for any n, after k seconds if k is a power of 2, as long as k is less than n there seems to be a large number of bulbs that are on in the beginning and a large number that are off at the end. Then I realized that the number that are on is exactly equal to k. That is, after k seconds $L_1, L_2,...,L_k$ are on and the rest are off, if $k$ is a power of 2, which I proved with induction. Now that that's proved, we can clearly see that for all n = $2^k$, in the n + 1th second, all bulbs turn off. That completes part a.

Comment: Right, so without tail end effects, the $k = 2^m < \approx n$ seconds positions have a very nice description where all $k$ bulbs are on. In fact, the $ k < \approx n$ also has a (less) nice description (might be a bit tougher to describe, but think binary). However, tail end effects are a pain to deal with once $ n > \approx k$ (as hinted by my initial comment), and so we need to figure out how to deal with them. Part b can be done with one more observation (by following my list above)  (Note: I'm using "approximate inequalities" because I'm not nailing down exactly when things breakdown)

Answer (score 2):

(Getting one more old question off the unanswered list.)

We can represent each possible state of $L_1,\ldots,L_n$ by a bit string $b_1\ldots b_n$ of length $n$, where $b_k=1$ if $L_k$ is on, and $b_k=0$ if $L_k$ is off. For $k\in\Bbb N$ let $\beta_n^{(k)}$ be the bit string representing the state of the lights $L_1,\ldots,L_n$ after $k$ seconds, so that $\beta_n^{(0)}=10^{n-1}$, where for $b\in\{0,1\}$ and $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$ we write

$$b^\ell=\underbrace{bb\ldots bb}_{\ell\,b\text{s}}\,.$$

A modest amount of computation suggests the following theorem.

> **Theorem.** Let $m\in\Bbb Z^+$, and let $n=2^m$. Then
> $$\begin{align*}
> (i)&\quad\beta_n^{(n-1)}=1^n\,;\\
> (ii)&\quad\beta_n^{(n)}=0^n\,;\text{ and}\\
> (iii)&\quad\beta_{n+1}^{(2n+1)}=\beta_{n+1}^{(1)}=110^{(n-1)}\,.
> \end{align*}$$

Suppose that the theorem is true; $(ii)$ says that when $n=2^m$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$, all $n$ lights are switched off after $n$ seconds, and clearly there are infinitely many such $n$. Next, note that if $\beta_{n+1}^{(k)}=0^{n+1}$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, then $\beta_{n+1}^{(\ell)}=0^{n+1}$ for all $\ell\ge k$. (I.e., once all $n+1$ lights are off, they remain off thereafter.) However, it follows from $(iii)$ by an easy induction on $k$ that $\beta_{n+1}^{(2k(n-1)+1)}=110^{n-1}\ne 0^{n+1}$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. That is, the lights will never all be off simultaneously if $n=2^m+1$, and of course there are infinitely many such $n$. (One can in fact show in this case that every state after the first will have at least two lights on.) Thus, we need only prove the theorem in order to establish the desired result. I will sketch a proof.

> It’s useful first to observe that if $0\le k\le n-1$, and $\beta_n^{(k)}=b_1\ldots b_n$, then $b_{k+1}$ is the rightmost $1$ in $\beta_n^{(k)}$, i.e., $b_{k+1}=1$, and $b_\ell=0$ for $k+1<\ell\le n$; this is easily shown by a finite induction on $k$.
>
> We prove $(i)$ by induction on $m$; it clearly holds for $m=1$. Suppose that it holds for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$, and let $n=2^m$. Then $\beta_{2n}^{(n-1)}=1^n0^n$, so $\beta_{2n}^{(n)}=0^{n-1}110^{n-1}$. The rules for passing from one state to the next are bilaterally symmetric, and with a little thought it follows from this that for $k=n,\ldots,2n-1$, the bit strings $\beta_{2n}^{(k)}$ are symmetric. That is, if $\beta_{2n}^{(k)}=b_1^{(k)}\ldots b_{2n}^{(k)}$, then $b_1^{(k)}\ldots b_n^{(k)}$ is the reversal of $b_{n+1}^{(k)}\ldots b_{2n}^{(k)}$.
>
> Now suppose that $n\le k<2n-1$; $b_n^{(k)}=b_{n+1}^{(k)}$, so whether $b_n^{(k+1)}=b_n^{(k)}$ depends solely on $b_{n-1}^{(k)}$, and whether $b_{n+1}^{(k+1)}=b_{n+1}^{(k)}$ depends solely on $b_{n+2}^{(k)}$. This implies that $b_{n+1}^{(k)}\ldots b_{2n}^{(k)}=\beta_n^{k-n}=$ whenever $n+1\le k\le 2n-1$; in particular, $b_{n+1}^{(2n-1)}\ldots b_{2n}^{(2n-1)}=1^n$, and therefore $\beta_{2n}^{(2n-1)}=1^{2n}$, as desired. By induction $(i)$ holds for all $m\in\Bbb Z^+$.
>
> Clearly $(i)$ implies $(ii)$ for any $m\in\Bbb Z^+$.
>
> To prove $(iii)$, note first that it follows from $(i)$ that $\beta_{n+1}^{(n-1)}=1^n0$ and hence that $\beta_{n+1}^{(n)}=0^{n-1}11$. This is the reversal of $\beta_{n+1}^{(1)}=110^{n-1}$, so $\beta_{n+1}^{(n+k)}$ must be the reversal of $\beta_{n+1}^{(k+1)}$ for $0\le k<n$. In particular, $\beta_{n+1}^{(2n-1)}$ is the reversal of $\beta_{n+1}^{(n)}=0^{n-1}11$, i.e., $\beta_{n+1}^{(2n-1)}=110^{n-1}=\beta_{n+1}^{(1)}$, as desired.